# Careers Automatic tag suggestions' layout is broken in Chrome 38

Tags: bug, jobs

The "Tag suggest" functionality when editing Open Source projects in one's Careers 2.0 profile is broken (i.e. the **layout is broken**, you can still "use" the feature) when using Chrome 38 on Windows (did not test other browsers).

See this screenshot:[image]

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was searching for the "tag" keyword all the time, so I could not find this one :) - Thanks for the heads up and please close!